# Adjusting cells width and height in excel in mm/cm through python script

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwt

I tried to look for it but couldn't find one. Is there a possibility to adjust the width,height of cells in excel in mm or cm dimensions using openpyxl or xlwt modules? if yes then can someone point me to the commands for scripting? thanks a lot.

Comment: Excel uses "characters" for column widths and row heights. How these render depends largely on the operating system used to view the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With Openpyxl**

To set column width:

```
#setting width of column B to 12.25
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = float(12.25)
```

To set Row height:

```
#setting height of row 3 to 33.75
sheet.row_dimensions[3].height = float(33.75)
```

**Hiding Columns and Rows**

Using the dimensions we can also hide rows and columns:

```
#Hiding Column B
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].hidden = True
```

And with rows

```
#Hiding Row 3
sheet.row_dimensions[3].hidden = True
```

Comment: thanks .is this 12.25 in mm or cm? also can I access column_dimensions with an integer instead of string 'B'?

Comment: The number is based on `characters` - I've had to add float(0.73) to the dimensions to have accurate measurements.

Comment: Has to be `string` but you can have a `list` and call the index number to represent that `column`

Comment: `column_reference =  [k[0].column for k in sheet.columns]` - this will give you a list for every column in your sheet

Comment: yeah got it. wb.rows and wb.columns. Thanks

Comment: FWIW you can group column dimensions together using `sheet.column_dimensions.group('A', 'K')` or simply setting the `min` and `max` for the column dimensions. But you can also set the defaultColWidth and defaultRowHeight for individual worksheets: `sheet.sheet_format.defaultColWidth = 12.25`

Comment: How do I find this point to mm conversion for printing an empty cell on a paper?