# Applying row height to all rows including and after row 7

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-3.7

I cannot figure out how to apply a row height on an existing worksheet unless I do it one row at a time.

This works for a single row:

```
ws4.row_dimensions[14].height = 25
```

But I want to set the row height for row 7 and any subsequent rows.

This approach does nothing yet does not throw an error:

```
for rows in ws4.iter_rows(min_row=7, max_row=None):
    ws4.row_dimensions.height = 25
wb4.save('C:\\folder\\DataplusRows.xlsx')
```

Any idea how to do this? I can't glean the answer from the openpyxl documentation. And I can't seem to find examples anywhere.

Comment: Interested in whole sheet though as well. I cant figure out documentation.

Comment: ***"Row 7 until the max row"***: This is a `range` of `rows`, you have to do it `row` by `row`

Comment: What might that look like?

Comment: ***"Interested in whole sheet though as well"***: Relevant [set-or-change-default-height-of-table-in-openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595131/how-to-set-or-change-default-height-of-table-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Comment**: There must be something in my sheet preventing me from setting the row height.

Tested with existing Workbook, `load_workbook(...`,
the Rows `4 - 6` set to `.height = 48`, are shown OK.

Relevant:

- [column-and-row-dimensions-in-openpyxl-are-always-none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855656/column-and-row-dimensions-in-openpyxl-are-always-none)
- [adjusting-cells-width-and-height-in-excel-in-mm-cm-through-python-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611920/adjusting-cells-width-and-height-in-excel-in-mm-cm-through-python-script)

> **Question**: Applying row height to all rows including and after row 7

[image]

> **Note**: Test `Workscheet` has 6 Rows, starting at Row 4.

```
import openpyxl 

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for _ in range(6):
    ws.append(('TEST' for _ in range(4)))

for row in range(4, ws.max_row + 1):
    ws.row_dimensions[row].height = 48

# wb.save(...)
```

Comment: I ran your exact code on a new workbook and worksheet and it worked. There must be something in my sheet preventing me from setting the row height. Maybe formatting such as freeze pains, sorting, etc. Thanks for the help.