# write python list of dicts to xlsx using openpyxl

Tags: python, image, openpyxl

i try to write this `list` of `dicts` into `xlsx` file using `openpyxlsx`

```
products= [{'id':46329', 
            'discription':'AD BLeu', 
            'marque':'AZERT',
            'category':'liquid',
            'family': 'ADBLEU', 
            'photos':'D:\\hamzawi\\hamza\\image2py\\46329_1.png'},
            {dict2 ...},
            {dictn...}
           ]
```

---

```
 # creat a workbook
 filena = "produitimage.xlsx"
 workbook = Workbook()
 sheet = workbook.active
 #add headers
 sheet.append(["Product ID", "Product Name", "Marque",
          "Category", "Family", "Photos"])
 for product in products:
    for item in product.items():
        for row, entry in enumerate(item, start=3):
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=entry)
 #add some images
 images = [item['photos'] for item in products]
 for image in images:
     logo = Image(image)
     #logo.height = 150
     #logo.width = 150
     sheet.add_image(logo)
 workbook.save(filename=filena)
```

i got xlsx file with only headers no data

Comment: [applying-row-height-to-all-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368340/applying-row-height-to-all-rows-including-and-after-row-7)

Comment: it s done Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Question**: append `list` of `dict`

```
import openpyxl

products = [{'id':46329, 
             'discription':'AD BLeu', 
             'marque':'AZERT',
             'category':'liquid',
             'family': 'ADBLEU', 
             'photos':'D:\\hamzawi\\hamza\\image2py\\46329_1.png'}
            ]

# Dictionarys are not in order by default
# Define a `list` of `keys` in desired order
fieldnames = ['id', 'discription', 'marque', 'category', 'family', 'photos']

# create a new workbook
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# append headers
ws.append(["Product ID", "Product Name", "Marque", "Category", "Family", "Photos"])

# append data
# iterate `list` of `dict`
for product in products:
    # create a `generator` yield product `value`
    # use the fieldnames in desired order as `key`
    values = (product[k] for k in fieldnames)

    # append the `generator values`
    ws.append(values)

# show Worksheet Values
for row_values in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    for value in row_values:
        print(value, end='\t')
    print()
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Product ID  Product Name    Marque  Category    Family  Photos  
> 46329       AD BLeu         AZERT   liquid      ADBLEU  D:\hamzawi\hamza\image2py\46329_1.png
> ```

---

If you want the image, instead of the image file path, change the following:

```
# remove 'photos' from fieldnames
fieldnames = \
['id', 'discription', 'marque', 'category', 'family']

# you need the Row index, add a `enumerate(..., 2)`
for row, product in enumerate(products,2):
    values = (product[k] for k in fieldnames)
    sheet.append(values)

    # after append the `values` add the image
    # Here, Column 'F'
    ws.add_image(Image(product['photos']), 'F{}'.format(row))
```

Comment: You can, of course, pass a generator expression into append.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code.
First, you are incrementing `next_row` value in the loop where you setting it, so increment doesn't have effect and every iteration the value of `next_row` equals 3.
Second, you are trying to write a list of dict values to excel cell, but I think you want it will be written as a row. So you need to just append it as you did with header above the loops:

```
for product in products:
    sheet.append(list(product.values()))
```

If you need to insert an image in last cell in a row you may rewrite loop that way:

```
for row_index, product in enumerate(products):
    values = list(product.values())
    sheet.append(values[:-1])
    col_row = get_column_letter(len(values)) + str(row_index+1) 
    photo_path = values[-1]
    sheet.add_image(Image(photo_path), col_row)
```

Comment: i do what you suggest but i got an error  TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'dict_values'>

Comment: That is because you are trying to save a `product.values()` as a cell value. I described it in my answer. `product.values()` has type `dict_values` so you need to convert it to `list` or `tuple` and append to `sheet`.

Comment: @hamzachenni I made a mistake in first block of code. I fixed it now, check the answer again.

Comment: i got some rusulte with                                                                                          
 for product in products:
    for item in product.items():
        sheet.append(item)

Comment: What exactly you want to do? You want to insert values of dict as a row or as a column?

Comment: Thank you very much chopchopa    plaese  how can the images into cells of column 'F' 'photos'